# How do I download bicycle routes data from OpenCycleMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to get bicycle routes data (vector data/shapefile) of major cities of Europe.

Can someone tell me how to download the bicycle routes shown in the [OpenCycleMap](https://www.opencyclemap.org/) map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCycleMap data are available as a layer on OpenStreetMap.
[In fact](https://www.opencyclemap.org/docs/),

> The OpenCycleMap global cycling map is based on data from the OpenStreetMap project.
>   The map is updated every few days with the latest data from OpenStreetMap.

Thus, see [this](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/33920/how-to-download-transport-data) similar question on help.openstreetmap.org.

You can try [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), if your area is small enough. Basically, the query should be like this:

```
[out:json][timeout:90]; 
area["name"="Københavns Kommune"]->.a; 
(   
  way["highway"="cycleway"](area.a);
  rel["route"="bicycle"](area.a); 
); 
out geom;
```

[Link to the query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/yE7), select *Settings > Map > Don't display small features as POIs*, if you want.

You could also ask your question on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap).

Comment: Note that your query combines "official" bicycle routes (`route=bicycle`) as well as all kind of ways designated for cycling (`highway=cycleway`). The latter must not necessarily belong to a cycle route. Also, if you are really looking for all kind of ways intended for cycling then better also add `bicycle=designated`. `highway=cycleway` isn't enough since cycling can also be allowed on ways tagged as `highway=path` and `highway=footway`.